# React + Typescript context - how to define interface and use it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use react context and I'm not sure how to use it correctly with typescript.

```
interface ITodoContext {
  todos: Todo[] | null;
  currentlyEditingTodoID: number|null;

  editTodo(todo: Todo): () => void
}

export const TodoContext = React.createContext<ITodoContext>({
  todos: null,
  // how do put the editTodo() ? 
});
```

The `editTodo` method will set `currentlyEditingTodoID` to the todo.id, and it might show a modal or something if its not null.

However, I'm not sure how to define the method correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to define methods is:

```
  editTodo: (todo: Todo) => void
```

Comment: How would I put that in the `React.createContext<ITodoContext>({ editTodo: someValue })`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should define your type and then your implementation:

```
interface ITodoContext {
  todos: Todo[] | null;
  currentlyEditingTodoID: number | null;
  editTodo: (todo: Todo) => void;
}

export const TodoContext = React.createContext<ITodoContext>({
  todos: null,
  currentlyEditingTodoID: null,
  editTodo(todo) {
    // your implementation of the function
  },
});
```

You can also use arrow notation for the function :

```
export const TodoContext = React.createContext<ITodoContext>({
  todos: null,
  currentlyEditingTodoID: null,
  editTodo: (todo) => {
    // your implementation of the function
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  if that `editTodo` is going to call some useState setter, can I keep it blank?  Thanks